# Exportar quiero los datos de un datagridview a pdf c#

Tags: c#

Quiero  exportar los datos de un datagridview a pdf.
Programo en c# visual basic 2012

Encontré este código pero  no se como cambiar o meter los datos del gridview

```
        // Creamos el documento con el tamaño de página tradicional
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
        // Indicamos donde vamos a guardar el documento
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc,
                                    new FileStream(@"C:\prueba.pdf", FileMode.Create));

        // Le colocamos el título y el autor
        // **Nota: Esto no será visible en el documento
        doc.AddTitle("Mi primer PDF");
        doc.AddCreator("Roberto Torres");

        // Abrimos el archivo
        doc.Open();

        // Escribimos el encabezamiento en el documento
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Mi primer documento PDF"));
        doc.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

        iTextSharp.text.Font _standardFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

        // Creamos una tabla que contendrá el nombre, apellido y país 
        // de nuestros visitante.
        PdfPTable tblPrueba = new PdfPTable(3);
        tblPrueba.WidthPercentage = 100;

        // Configuramos el título de las columnas de la tabla
        PdfPCell clNombre = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Nombre", _standardFont));
        clNombre.BorderWidth = 0;
        clNombre.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;

        PdfPCell clApellido = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Apellido", _standardFont));
        clApellido.BorderWidth = 0;
        clApellido.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;

        PdfPCell clPais = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("País", _standardFont));
        clPais.BorderWidth = 0;
        clPais.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;

        // Añadimos las celdas a la tabla
        tblPrueba.AddCell(clNombre);
        tblPrueba.AddCell(clApellido);
        tblPrueba.AddCell(clPais);

        // Llenamos la tabla con información
        clNombre = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Roberto", _standardFont));
        clNombre.BorderWidth = 0;

        clApellido = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Torres", _standardFont));
        clApellido.BorderWidth = 0;

        clPais = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Puerto Rico", _standardFont));
        clPais.BorderWidth = 0;

        // Añadimos las celdas a la tabla
        tblPrueba.AddCell(clNombre);
        tblPrueba.AddCell(clApellido);
        tblPrueba.AddCell(clPais);

        clNombre = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Juan", _standardFont));
        clNombre.BorderWidth = 0;

        clApellido = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Rodríguez", _standardFont));
        clApellido.BorderWidth = 0;

        clPais = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("México", _standardFont));
        clPais.BorderWidth = 0;

        tblPrueba.AddCell(clNombre);
        tblPrueba.AddCell(clApellido);
        tblPrueba.AddCell(clPais);

        // Finalmente, añadimos la tabla al documento PDF y cerramos el documento
        doc.Add(tblPrueba);

        doc.Close();
        writer.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("¡PDF creado!");
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Debes contarnos que has intentado y probado hasta ahora

Comment: Debes aportar algo mas de información. ¿Sabes como cargar el grid? ¿Sabes recorrerlo para recoger sus filas?. si no es asi mírate este enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737436/looping-each-row-in-datagridview

Cuando tengas el grid cargado, debes generar un método a parte para crear el documento PDF, recorriendo cada fila del grid y generando una tabla de celdas con los valores del grid.

Comment: Encontré un artículo interesante de [Exportación de un DataGridView a un archivo de imagen / Excel / PDF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28269/Exporting-a-DataGridView-to-an-Excel-PDF-image-fil) la información esta en inglés pero fácilmente puedes traducirla usando GoogleTraductor, Saludos!

Comment: – Raúl si se como cargar el Grid pero no encuentro un método adecuado para generar el PDF.
solo encuentro en ASP.NET o VB.NET.  y necesito uno para c# 2012